# Apache Camel: how to get a correct mock endpoint for beanRef?

Tags: mocking, apache-camel

I have a route like this

```
from("direct:start").beanRef("someBean");
```

For a unit test I try to get mock endpoint for it, but expectedMessageCount condition is not satisfied.

```
MockEndpoint beanMock = getMockEndpoint("mock:bean:someBean");
beanMock.expectedMessageCount(1);
```

If I change my route into this, everything works fine.

```
from("direct:start").to("bean:someBean");
```

The folowing does not work either:

```
MockEndpoint beanMock = getMockEndpoint("mock:ref:someBean");
```

How to get a correct mock endpoint for beanRef?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `beanRef` does not produce an endpoint, so you can not access it by `getMockEndPoint`. if you want to test the result of your bean, you can add a mock endPoint and test its content.

here is an example:

```java
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class BeanRefMock extends CamelTestSupport {
    public static class SomeBean{
        public void handle(Exchange ex){
            System.out.println("SomeBean : " +ex);
            ex.getIn().setBody(ex.getIn().getBody() +" is Processed By Bean");
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
        CamelContext camelContext = super.createCamelContext();
        return camelContext;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport#createRouteBuilder()
     */
    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start").bean(SomeBean.class).to("mock:postBean");
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testQuoteCount() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:postBean");
        mockEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("hello mock is Processed By Bean");

        template.sendBody("direct:start", "hello mock");
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I still have 1 question. I have always wondered how camels folks give examples like this. Say, I have a production route `from(ACTIVE_MQ_Q1).bean('somebean').to(ACTIVE_MQ_Q2)`. Here I see no option in adding a mock endpoint: 1. mock endpoing can't be added to production route - it's not a correct way to build prod. 2. If I create a production-like testing route based on mocks, then I actually test exact that test-route, but not the production one. Can you please tell me what is wrong in my thoughts?

Comment: That is exactly where I can't get my head around, too. If someone has an answer I'd be relieved.

Comment: There are several possibilities for modifying a production route for testing using AOP. See the [AdviceWith](http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) documentation for further details. For example: use "mockEndpoints" to replace your JMS endpoints with mocks.